# How do I display a div tag as an example?

Tags: html

I am working on a how-to and I want to show on the user's screen the line like this:

Example: `<div class="something>Example</div>`

Obviously, the browser will render it as an actual div so how do I display it as just text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
&lt;div class="something&gt;Example&lt;/div&gt;
```

[HTML encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code for less than or greater than: < and >

```
&lt;div class="something"&gt;Example&lt;/div&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the said text in Stack Overflow, and viewing the selection source, the source for your code block is

```
<code>&lt;div class="something&gt;Example&lt;/div&gt;</code>
```

in Stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
&lt div &gt Your things here &lt/div &gt
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CDATA to display code: `<![CDATA[Your <code> here]]>`
This may not work with all browsers.